# Declaring a variant type more specifically as a collection

Tags: vba

This is an extract of a sub-routine I use lot:

```
Private Sub DeleteFilesNotCreatedToday(myTargetFolder As String)

Dim myFolder
Dim myFile
Dim YesterdayDate As Date

YesterdayDate = Date
Set myFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(myTargetFolder).Files

For Each myFile In myFolder

...
...
Next myFile
```

Why can't I declare `myFolder` more specifically instead of variant - or can I? I've tried declaring it as a collection but it errors...

```
Private Sub DeleteFilesNotCreatedToday(myTargetFolder As String)

Dim myFolder As Collection
Dim myFile
Dim YesterdayDate As Date

YesterdayDate = Date
Set myFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder(myTargetFolder).Files

For Each myFile In myFolder

...
...
Next myFile
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set a reference to microsoft scripting runtime and declare it as `Dim myFolder As Scripting.Folder`

Edit

To get a collection of files use the files collection in the scripting runtime library. An example is shown below.

```
Sub CollectFiles()

Dim myFile As Scripting.File
Dim myFolder As scripting.folder
Set myFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder("C:\")

For Each myFile In myFolder.Files
Next myFile

End Sub
```

Edit2 : If you want to dimension myFolder as a collection of files rather than a folder you can do it the following way:

```
Sub CollectFiles()

Dim myFile As Scripting.File
Dim myFolder As Scripting.Files
Set myFolder = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder("C:\").Files

For Each myFile In myFolder
Next myFile

End Sub
```

It might get a bit confusing if people expect it to be a folder rather than a files collection so it would probably better to rename it.

Comment: reference already in place. `Scripting.Folder` is a collection?

Comment: The short answer is that it represents a system folder. In the VBE you can pres F2 to view the object browser, the top drop down box in this view allows you to look at the objects in a library. This will give you an idea of the different objects and there properties/methods.

Comment: The folder object has a file collection in it it can be accessed via myFolder.Files

Comment: You can create the file collection e.g. using `Dim collectionFiles As Scripting.Files`
and set it using `Set collectionFiles = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject").GetFolder("C:\").Files`